# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

My code below:

```
int userId = 42;
String stringIdBook = "42";
User user = daoUser.getUser(userId);
List<Books> booksOrderedByUser = user.getBooks();

for (Books x : booksOrderedByUser) {
    System.out.println(x.getTitle());
}

for (Books x : booksOrderedByUser) {
    String idBookString = Integer.toString(x.getIdBook());
    if (idBookString == stringIdBook) {
        booksOrderedByUser.remove(x.getIdBook());
        break;
    }

}

for (Books x : booksOrderedByUser) {
    System.out.println(x.getTitle());
}

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.merge(booksOrderedByUser);
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

entityManager.close();
```

When i run this jpa i got this exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:839)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:821)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:826)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161)
    at servlet.returnBookServlet.doPost(returnBookServlet.java:59)
```

This code gets list of books which belong to user and delete selected. First issue is book isn't removed(I print list of books via `System.out.println()` and list is same before and after `booksOrderedByUser.remove(x.getIdBook()`). Second issue is this exception during merge. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: merge takes in an Entity not a List.

Comment: I fixed problem with list but some one can tell me how can i save this is database?

Answer (score 2):

First of all,  use `equals` to compare String values, not `==` .

Second thing is, your `List` contains `Books` objects, so calling :

```
remove(x.getIdBook())
```

has no chance to succeed.

What you want here is removing a `Books` object from the list, not a `String` object or whatever, so go this way :

```
remove(x)
```

Finally, you may want to rename your `Books` class to `Book`, since it represents only one book .

Comment: Thanks, that fix my problem with list but still don't know how to save it in database

Comment: Try merging the user instead.